# Edit magento labels, locate the files

Tags: magento-1.7

Does anyone know where I can find the Magento product label file(s)

I'm looking to edit the text for New and Sales labels

Answer (score 1):

The translation files are located in `app/locale/`. They are quite descriptive, so anything related to products should be in `Mage_Catalog.csv` but you can run a quick `grep` in this folder, to find the exact string you're trying to replace.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I cant seem to locate it there. The div class im trying to edit is labels top-left on the category page